# How to get a hash of a Java class' structure?

Tags: java, reflection

Imagine I have the following two classes:

```java
public class A {
    private String field1;
    private B field2;
}

public class B {
    private String field3;
}
```

What I want to do is use Java Reflection to get all the fields and all the subfields from class A and create a hash out of it. In this example, I would get, say, a list of Strings saying `["field1", "field2", "field3"]`, and I would hash the entire list.

In case it helps, the reason I am doing this is because I have a MongoDB collection for `A`. However, every once in a while, I add new fields to `A` or `B`, and I need to refresh the entire collection with the new fields when that happens. For this, I need to keep track, in a separate collection, of whether I have already refreshed `A`'s collection yet or not for its current structure. The easiest way would be to just hash its fields and subfields names.

Comment: Looks like you’re reinventing the serialVersionUID. When your class implements `Serializable`, you can simply use [`ObjectStreamClass.lookup(A.class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectStreamClass.html#lookup(java.lang.Class))[`.getSerialVersionUID()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectStreamClass.html#getSerialVersionUID()).

Answer (score 2):

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/FieldUtils.html#getAllFieldsList-java.lang.Class- sounds like it could be a sufficient solution to your problem.

Addresssing a comment, `getAllFieldsList` returns `List<Field>` so you should be able to iterate or recurse through that `List` and then call `Field.getType()` which returns `Class`. Now call  `getAllFieldsList` again. This should let you traverse from Class A then get information about Class B.

Another idea might be to use the JSON_STYLE and call `https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html#ReflectionToStringBuilder-java.lang.Object-org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle-`. This will recurse and print out JSON representing `A` then you can parse the JSON and check the field names.

Another pathway might be to handle this at compile time or package time. Unless you're using other reflection or aspect oriented programming techniques your classes will only change in development at compile time. Detecting changes as part of your build or CI/CD processes then feeding those into your MongoDB may make more sense.

Comment: That method seems like exactly what I need! However, it says it gets the fields of the class and its parents. I want to get the children though (cuz `B` would be a child of `A`).
Also, I like your suggestion of doing at compile time in my pipeline, as I would not be changing the class structurer at runtime. Do you have any suggestions on how to do that?